# How to make purrr recognize colnames of df in a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to unite first and last names in each dataframe in a list of dataframes. The problem is that purrr doesn't seem to recognize colnames *within* each df.

Each df in data$authors_list looks something like

| authid | surname | given-name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Smith | John |
| 85858 | Scott | Jane |

I want to unite the "surname" and "given-names" into a column called AuN.

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(authors_list = map(authors_list,
                            unite(col=AuN,
                            c(`given-name`,
                              surname),
                            sep = " ")))
```

However, I get the following error.

```
Error in unite(col = AuN, c(`given-name`, surname), sep = " ") : 
  object 'given-name' not found
```

I am new to using purrr, and I haven't been able to find solutions to a similar problem online. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have data.frames stored inside of data.frame columns? Please provide a reproducible example using something like `dput()` so we can copy/paste the sample data into R for testing. you don't seem to be passing a function to `map`, you seem to be calling one which is likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. You need to put in `.x` in the unite call to stand in for each data frame in the list. For each one, it will unite with the parameters you specified.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Set up the data (but please in the future give us data so we don't have to set it up)
df <- tibble(authid = c(12345, 85858), surname = c("Smith", "Scott"), `given-name` = c("John","Jane"))
list_df <- list(df, df, df)

list_df_unite <- map(list_df, ~ unite(.x, AuN, c(`given-name`,surname), sep = " "))
```